# My Homepage Suddenly Disappeared and I Can't Get It Back

Tags: htaccess, errors, 404-error, homepage, troubleshooting

All of a sudden my website's homepage (a static page operating as my storefront) disappeared, and its now displaying a blog feed of the latest posts. If I click through on any of these posts in the blog feed it returns a 404 ("oops, page has been moved or doesn't exist").

When I go to Settings>Reading, I see that indeed my site is still set to display static page/my storefront as the homepage.

I should mention that I have installed no new plugins or made any recent changes -- the only thing I've been doing is creating a lot of new product pages as drafts. I also have had auto theme and plugin updates disabled for over a year now, so it can't be an auto plugin update issue.

I figured the issue might be related to .htaccess, so I went to settings>permalinks and pressed the save button. And when that didn't work, I then deleted my .htaccess from cpanel so it would generate a new one. But still that didn't work.

I have no idea what the issue could be? Like I said, the only recent changes I've made is adding about 100 new product pages (and uploading about 400 product images to my website) over the past day or so as drafts.

For some reason my website will just no longer display any static page as the homepage. Any help on how to fix it?

Comment: after you "resaved" your permalink structure did wp create a new .htaccess file?